# How can I make the suggestions widget appear "automatically" for a completion provider in a VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions, code-completion

*Full extension source code is [here](https://github.com/teamtreesurf/link/tree/make/code).*

I have this config in my extension `package.json`:

```
"contributes": {
  "configurationDefaults": {
    "[link]": {
      "editor.wordWrap": "on",
      "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "on",
        "strings": "on"
      },
      "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
      "editor.wordSeparators": " ()<>{},?/",
      "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

I also have this in my language server.

```
connection.onCompletion(
  (_textDocumentPosition: TextDocumentPositionParams): CompletionItem[] => {
    connection.console.log('here');
    const keywords = documentKeywords.get(_textDocumentPosition.textDocument.uri) ?? [];
    connection.console.log(JSON.stringify(keywords));

    return keywords.map((keyword, i) => ({
      label: keyword,
      kind: CompletionItemKind.Text,
      data: i + 1
    }));
  }
);
```

I am only able to trigger the code completion by pressing `CTRL+SPACE`, as seen in this video.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work automatically without this keyboard shortcut?

I have it turned off globally.

[image]

But even if I turn it on, it doesn't work. I will note, even with the global setting off, JavaScript/TypeScript is still getting code completion:

[image]

Wondering what I am missing? What do I need to enable or configure, or why do you think it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is space as a trigger character:

```
const result: InitializeResult = {
    capabilities: {
        textDocumentSync: TextDocumentSyncKind.Incremental,
        completionProvider: {
            resolveProvider: true,
            triggerCharacters: ["-", " "],
        },
    },
};
```

I believe `editor.wordSeparators` is unrelated to code suggestions.

For reference, since you brought up the TypeScript behavior as an example, these are their trigger characters (via [typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/completions.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/68efb6fe56bd1476e3642ba5752930ce021f5fad/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/completions.ts#L665)):

```
triggerCharacters = ['.', '"', '\'', '`', '/', '@', '<', '#', ' '];
```

I recommend poking around in the [`extensions/` folder of the vscode repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions) if you're stuck implementing a language feature. For instance the `markdown-language-features` is fairly recent, and not as overwhelming as maybe the TypeScript extension.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `triggerCharacters` rest parameter of `registerCompletionItemProvider` ([link to docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)). When you register a completion item provider, you can specify what characters should be its trigger characters (characters that automatically trigger suggestions).

Fun fact: There's also a setting that users can use to disable the trigger characters feature: `editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters`.