# How to show field suggestions after typing brackets in TypeScript in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I type "b", it will suggest "bar". But what I want is showing the suggestions just after typing the brackets.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code as text as well as an image. The image can be left in this case for the purpose of showing the IDE UI.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes why?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15261914) For example, I want to copy the code so I can paste it into my IDE to test the behavior.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes do you think this issue is caused by the code?

Comment: No, but it provides a useful starting point, instead of having to recreate it.

Comment: Also: \* Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor in order to reproduce the problem. \* Images can be blocked by corporate proxies, certain school networks, and entire countries (notably China), and therefore the code isn't available to those readers. \* Users with poor network speeds may be unable to load certain images at all. Users with very restrictive data plans may even disable images entirely to save their data quota. \* The data dumps do not include images; any offline uses for the data dump, whether officially supported or not, won't see images at all.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes so you can not understand the point of the question without copying the code?

Comment: I can, but I want to be able to easily copy the code you provided to see what my editor and extensions do, instead of having to type it out. It's a simple matter of convenience, efficiency, and courtesy.

Comment: And someone who uses a screen reader will probably not be able to understand your question enough to help you, or to realize that this question is the same one they have (other than the title). (You provided no alt text for the image.)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes since the issue is not caused by the code, why you need to copy the code? On the other hand, if you have to reproduce the "issue", then you must not know the answer. In the question, image is better because it shows the cursor position and make better understanding.

Comment: slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77647178/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74837030/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. This is the key binding in Visual Studio Code for opening the suggestion menu.

Comment: Yes it showed up. But I have to type `ctrl+space` every time. Is there a way to make it show by default?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to make this happen automatically when you open brackets in VSC. I think you may have to use the keybind everytime.

Comment: I recall VS Code doing it once I had created a new line (so, hit enter after typing the left brace). It doesn't do that for me now, but I'm not sure what's changed.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an out of the box way, however you can create a key binding to do what you want.

In your keybindings.json, add the following key binding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+[",
  "when": "editorLangId == typescript",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "{"
        },
      },
      {
        "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There are two commands, one for writing the `{` character since it is used for key binding and the second to trigger the suggestion.

Edit:

I found that it becomes a pain when you just wants to create a function, etc...

I have updated the "key" value to be `cmd+shift+[` for now, until I find a better way.